# Handler.removeCallbacks(null)

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, handler

there is a use "Handler.removeCallbacks(null)", but my IDE gives me a tip that "null cannot be a value of a non-null type Runnable", what should i do?

I'd like to create an abstract method to remove all messages

Comment: The `removeCallbacks` method first parameter is a `Runnable`, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable). Therefore, you should pass a `Runnable` instead of `null`.

Comment: You cannot pass null value here because removeCallbacks accept only non-null type. Can you explain a bit what's your requirement in a bit detail ?

Comment: I casually came across an article, the article mentioned a paragraph code "mHandler.removeCallbacks(null)". In fact I see the prompt in Android Stutio, then I check the source code. But it confused me that why the author wrote this or If there is a grammer I dont know.

Comment: You can share a link so we can take a look at it, but probably it's just a bad article